# How to terminate the cookie whenever I login?

Tags: java, cookies, authentication, logout

I have these login codes which validates whether the username matches the password. After I login, I would like to terminate the cookie whenever I login and logout. How will I do it?

**LoginAuthentication.java**

```
package com.dls.csb.process.web.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.ats.model.Account;
import com.dls.csb.utility.SQLOperations;
import com.dls.csb.utility.Security;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@WebServlet("/loginauthentication.html")
public class LoginAuthentication extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     
ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
       String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
       String passWord = Security.encrypt(request.getParameter("passWord"));
       String passwordInput = request.getParameter("passWord");
       Account acct = new Account(userName, passWord);
       HttpSession session = request.getSession();
       if(userName.equals("admin103457") && passwordInput.equals("juliefefe")) {
           response.sendRedirect("admin.jsp");
           session.setAttribute("userName", acct);

       }

       else {

       boolean isValidLogon = false;
       try {

         isValidLogon = SQLOperations.authenticateLogin(acct);
         if(isValidLogon) {
            session.setAttribute("userName", acct);
            response.sendRedirect("main.jsp");

            }

         else {
             response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

         }
       }
        catch(Exception e) {
         e.getMessage();
       }
       }

}  
}
```

**ProcessRegistration.java**

```
package com.dls.csb.process.web.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import com.ats.model.Account;
import com.dls.csb.utility.SQLOperations;
import com.dls.csb.utility.Security;

@WebServlet("/processregistration.html")
public class ProcessRegistration extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String passwordInput = request.getParameter("passWord");
    String passWord = Security.encrypt(request.getParameter("passWord"));
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String middleName = request.getParameter("middleName");
    String nationality = request.getParameter("nationality");
    String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
    String country = request.getParameter("country");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    int statusID = 1;
    String checkPassword = request.getParameter("cPassword");
    Account acct = new Account(userName, passWord, lastName, firstName, middleName,    
nationality, gender, country, email, statusID);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher;   

   if (checkPassword.equals(passwordInput)) {


           if (SQLOperations.addAccount(acct)){
            System.out.println("successful insert");
            request.setAttribute("account", acct);
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("status.jsp?success=true");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
           else  {
            System.out.println("failed insert");
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("status.jsp?success=false");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
           }
        }
        else  {
            System.out.println("Must matched password");
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("status.jsp?success=false");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }        
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you can do:

cookie.setMaxAge(0);

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge%28int%29